# Kubuntu missing icons

Tags: ubuntu, icons

I was using Manjaro with KDE, since i decide to change to Ubuntu world y choose Kubuntu, the installation was completely normal but when the system start the most part of icons are missing, as you can see.

[Kubuntu missing icons](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ai3TO.png)

I don't really found anything about this on the web and I really hope anyone could help me. Thanks to all. By the way Steam, Genymotion and some games that was installed on Manjaro the icons appear on desktop just like it was on Manjaro, but of course these doesn't work since wasn't installed on Kubuntu.

NOTE: Specs.
CPU: i3-3220
RAM: 6gb
Disk: 1Tb
GPU: integrated intel graphic

Answer (score 0, accepted):

generally icons are kept in /usr/share/icons globally or ./local/share/icons  in your local home, however this is not a mandatory locations, applications can keep them elsewhere (mostly inside their own installation folders)

I would recommend changing the theme first (download one if o don't have any) and check what happened. 
You may also try this or search ask ubuntu for other answers

https://askubuntu.com/questions/621222/after-installation-kubuntu-some-application-launcher-icon-missing